# Form select button to insert info to db mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, forms

I need help here.. I want to create some form for submit data to db. I have no problem with the form and inserting data to db. but I stuck when I want to add new value to db table column. I have create 1 select button and on the select button value list from db column (e.g category). picture attached.

Top: select the value from db and input disable

bottom: select create new and input enable to create new value

Sorry stackoverflow does not allow me to attach img. Here is the link

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/121852/form-elements.jpg

Hope you guys are clear and can help me.. thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have no problem inserting data to db, why can't you just insert the new category?

Comment: sorry for not clear it up.. i have problem with select button like picture i linked.. to add new value.

Comment: You want to dynamically add the new category to the main dropdown? Either rebuild the whole page and add it then, or use ajax to submit it to the server and add it to the dropdown at the same time.

Comment: I mean when user post something and must select the category. whether the user select from the list or create new one. How to do that.. :(

the problem is how to create select button with create new option and enabling the input for the value.. google it but cant find. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: To clarify it up, you want: a) a select statement that makes a selection of the actual categories; and b) an insert statement that adds a new category. Right? Also, I'm guessing that you are using a SQL db with a table and you want to select/insert onto a defined column (categories). Could you give us a quick view of that db structure?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you correctly - you want an final option on the select's options list with "create new one"?
Than you should give it a unique value like "createcategory" and put `onchange` event on that select box

```
<select name="..." onchange="javascript:checkSelect(this.value);">
```

As you can see - I called the javascript function `checkSelect` that you should create with somethis like that:

```
function checkSelect(val)
{
    if(val == "createcategory")
        document.getElementById('the_input_id').disabled = false;
    else
        document.getElementById('the_input_id').disabled = true;
}
```

What I did in this function is to check on every change of the select-box if the value of the selected option is "createcategory", and if so - I'm setting the text input disabled to false, so it would work, otherwise - I'm setting it again to true